# Display custom UIImageView when table view cell is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I am using custom `UIImageView` and `UITextField` on table view cell. All are working, but when I select any cell, imageview become hidden, but textfield shown . So what is the problem and how can I solve it ?

This is my code for using image and textfield on tableview -

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellidentitifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellidentitifier];
    if (cell ==nil)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentitifier];

    }
    else
    {
        [cell prepareForReuse];
    }

    UIImageView *imgview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 10, 68, 70)];
    imgview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    imgview.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    imgview.layer.cornerRadius =YES;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgview];

    _nameTF = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 10, 160, 20)];
    _nameTF.placeholder =@"Name";
    _nameTF.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_nameTF];
    _nameTF.delegate = self;
    _nameTF.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    _nameTF = nil;

    _addressTF = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 34, 160, 20)];
    _addressTF.placeholder = @"Address";
    _addressTF.layer.borderWidth= 1.0;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_addressTF];
    _addressTF.delegate = self;
    _addressTF.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    _addressTF = nil;


    _PhoneTF = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 58, 160, 20)];
    _PhoneTF.placeholder = @"Phone";
    _PhoneTF.layer.borderWidth= 1.0;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_PhoneTF];
    _PhoneTF.delegate = self;
    _PhoneTF.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    _PhoneTF = nil;

    _slotTF = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 84, 250, 18)];
    _slotTF.placeholder = @"Slot";
    _slotTF.layer.borderWidth= 1.0;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_slotTF];
    _slotTF.delegate = self;
    _slotTF.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    _slotTF = nil;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 UIImageView *imgview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 10, 68, 70)];
    imgview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    imgview.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    imgview.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    imgview.layer.cornerRadius =YES;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgview];
```

And you select a cell, you find that the imgview is still there
So,I think when select a cell, the background color of this cell become gray.So,the blackColor of imgview is covered。It is not hidden